# I want listen Connectivity changes when connection lost it show a error screen and when restored back to the current screen in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

hiiii i am new in flutter i just want to  listen NetWork changes when connection lost it show a error screen and when restored back to the current screen i am listening Connection  its printing on console but how can i show the error screen and when connection restored then show the current screen????`

```
 import 'dart:async';

  import 'package:connectivity_plus/connectivity_plus.dart';
  import 'package:get/get.dart';
   import 'package:internet_connection_checker/internet_connection_checker.dart';

  class ConnectionUtil extends GetxController{
  static ConnectionUtil getInstance()=> ConnectionUtil();
  bool  hasConnection = false;
  StreamController controller= StreamController();
  final Connectivity _connectivity = Connectivity();
   void initialize(){
   _connectivity.onConnectivityChanged.listen(_connectionChange);
   }
   void _connectionChange(ConnectivityResult result){
   hasInternetConnection();
    }
  Stream get change => controller.stream;
  Future<bool> hasInternetConnection()async{
  bool previousConnection = hasConnection;
  var connectivityResult = await (Connectivity().checkConnectivity());
  if(connectivityResult  == ConnectivityResult.wifi){
  print('connected wifi');
  if(await InternetConnectionChecker().hasConnection){
    print('connected');
    hasConnection = true;
  }else{
    hasConnection = false;
    print('connection not Availible');
  }
   }else{
   hasConnection = false;
     print('connected not Availible');
  }
  if (previousConnection != hasConnection) {
      controller.add(hasConnection);
  }
  return hasConnection;
 }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it in three steps :-

1. Create Connection Service

```
import 'package:connectivity/connectivity.dart';
import 'package:dio/dio.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';

class NetworkConnectivityController extends GetxController {
  var connected = true.obs;
  var exception = false.obs;

  final Connectivity _connectivity = Connectivity();
  @override
  void onInit() {
    checkConnectivity();
    _connectivity.onConnectivityChanged.listen((_connectivityResult) {
      _updateState(_connectivityResult);
    });
  }

  Future<void> checkConnectivity() async {
    var _connectivityResult;
    try {
      _connectivityResult = await _connectivity.checkConnectivity();
      _updateState(_connectivityResult);
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
      exception.value = true;
    }
  }

  Future<void> _updateState(ConnectivityResult _connectivityResult) async {
    switch (_connectivityResult) {
      case ConnectivityResult.none:
        connected.value = true;
        await Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 500));
        //NOTE: YOU CAN REMOVE THIS DELAY STATEMENT. SINCE I AM USING
        //THIS LOGIC IN MY PROJECT I USED IT TO HAVE SOME DELAY WHEN 
        //USER TAPS ON NETWORK RETRY BUTTON(IN MY PROJECT APPLICATION)
        connected.value = false;
        break;
      case ConnectivityResult.mobile:
      case ConnectivityResult.wifi:
        connected.value = await _checkIfWifiHasInternetAccess();
        break;
    }
    print('connection status' + connected.value.toString());
  }

  Future<bool> _checkIfWifiHasInternetAccess() async {
    try {
      var dio = Dio();
      var result = await dio.head('https://www.google.com/');
      return true;
    } catch (e) {
      return false;
    }
  }

  @override
  void onClose() {}
}
```

2. Create a binding class for it

```
import 'package:get/get.dart';
//your connectivity package => add import here

class NetworkConnectivityBinding extends Bindings{


  @override
  void dependencies() {
    // TODO: implement dependencies

    Get.lazyPut<NetworkConnectivityController>(() => NetworkConnectivityController());

  }


}
```

3. Add this binding to your GetMaterialApp function

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GetMaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(brightness: Brightness.light),
      initialBinding: NetworkConnectivityBinding(),
      //TODO: to add here the logic for dark and bright themes
      title: "Your title",
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: splashScreen(),
    );
  }
```

And at last you can now use your connectivity controller in any screen like below:-

```
  late NetworkConnectivityController _networkConnectivityController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    try {
      _networkConnectivityController = Get.find();
    } catch (e) {
      _networkConnectivityController = Get.put(NetworkConnectivityController());
    }

  }
```

And use `connected.value` to get the current status of network ... you don't have to do anything extra, that binding will do it for you to check connectivity status whenever the connection changes and accordingly update the value of `connected`.