# How to run a specific job in Flutter while using the application in all screens?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to run a specific job while using the mobile app without copying and pasting the code at every screen code. I have a lot of screens, and each screen is at a different dart file. I tried to use streams but it did not work.

Here is my code:

```dart
Stream.periodic(Duration(seconds: 5), (count) async {
                            final response = await get(
                              Uri.parse(
                                  'SOME REST API URI'),
                              headers: headers,
                            );
                            if (response.statusCode == 200) {
                              final responseDecoded =
                                  json.decode(response.body);
                              // Do something with the decoded response
                            }
                          });
```

The API call works fine, but the code is not being executed at all. I want this code to be executed every 5 seconds while using the app regardless of what screen the user at.

Comment: try using it https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/WidgetsBindingObserver-class.html

Comment: @AnkitKumarMaurya Shall I `implement` this class at each of my classes?

Comment: look at one of solutions here https://stackoverflow.com/a/71435343/15950932

Comment: @Ambitions You could create a function for this code and call the function on `initstate` or `build` of a page.

Comment: @Delwinn Your solution is great. However, this means that I should edit initState for every widget that I have. Which is something that I am trying to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

I was going to suggest using a `Mixin` (https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#adding-features-to-a-class-mixins), which is still possible, but having each individual Widget do this seems silly.

Instead, you should launch a separate Isolate (similar to what would be a thread in traditional languages). You can launch it from your `main` function and use something like a `Provider` to listen to its messages when it has some updates, or write straight to a file/database from the isolate.

A package like `flutter_isolate` (https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_isolate) can help if you want to use packages in this isolate. An isolate will keep running whatever the app is doing. Note that you do need to terminate it when the app closes.

Their examples should be sufficient to get you going.